# Forcing a POST on every checkbox/dropdown change

Tags: javascript, html, post

How can I force any change to a checkbox (inside a form) or to a drop-down menu selection to cause a HTTP POST to be issued by the browser?

Bandwidth is not an issue, page reloading is not an issue and I don't want to go the full AJAX route.

What I really want is an HTTP POST to be done when the user clicks on a checkbox (or selects something from a drop-down menu), etc. without the user having to click 'Submit' after its change.

Maybe it should be done with some JavaScript on the client-side? (I couldn't succesfully Google anything)

Comment: There's no "maybe", you'll need to submit a form on every change using JS.

Comment: If someone could explain the downvote it would be great.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's for a perceived lack of effort--this is easily searchable, despite your results. For example, https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=submit+form+on+checkbox+click&qscrl=1 seems to return quite a few related hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript. Add `onchange="document.getElementById('myFormId').submit()"` to the elements, or do this programatically. `myFormId` must be replaced by the HTML id of the `form` element.

Comment: +1 to everyone... Thanks a lot for your quick answer: works fine.

Comment: If you use inline and the object is inside the form to submit, then `onchange="this.form.submit()"` will do it too

Answer (score 1):

AFIK it can't be done without client-side scripting. The easiest way would be to trigger the `submit` event for every form change. With jQuery it's done with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],select").change(
      function(evt)){evt.target.form.submit();}
    );
});
</script>
```

If you don't use jQuery, you'll have to write some boilerplate event handling code. See [this introduction](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) for more info on JavaScript event handling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JavaScript onchange event to then call the submit() function on the form.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a form already set up just put a class to the element you want to use as trigger and then
for select

```
$(".classname").change(function(){
$("#formid").submit();
});
```

for checkbox/radio

```
$(".classname").click(function(){
$("#formid").submit();
});
```